# Commit hook to verify commit came from TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In my organization commits are supposed to come specifically through `TortoiseSVN`. I'm wanting to prevent a situation where someone accidentally commits to `SVN` through an `IDE` which has been integrated with `SVN`. Removing the IDE integration with SVN would solve this problem, but then the user would lose all other integration capabilities such as reverting, diffing between versions, etc. So I'm looking for a different solution. The IDE which is being used most does not have this capability either which is why I'm looking for a SVN solution.

If someone is using an IDE, there are shortcuts for committing. I'm trying to prevent the situation where someone is in their IDE and hit the commit shortcut (then enter) and accidentally commit to the repo without meaning to.

Is it possible to create a `SVN` commit hook which will only accept commits from `TortoiseSVN`?

Comment: What situation do you want to prevent? What problem do you want to solve? That's unclear.

Comment: If someone is using an IDE, there are shortcuts for committing. I'm trying to prevent the situation where someone is in their IDE and hit the commit shortcut (then enter) and accidentally commit to the repo without meaning to.

Comment: use a pre-commit hook to reject commits with empty log messages or log messages that don't use certain template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information is not available in commit hooks. You may want to configure the server to white or blacklist certain user-agents.

However, you are thinking about wrong approach. You better setup the pre-commit hook script that will process log messages.

> If someone is using an IDE, there are shortcuts for committing. I'm
>   trying to prevent the situation where someone is in their IDE and hit
>   the commit shortcut (then enter) and accidentally commit to the repo
>   without meaning to.

Users must enter informative log messages when they commit. You can force them to do this via pre-commit hook script. The hook can reject empty log messages or log messages that don't have certain text. This is what you are looking for -- it will help users avoid accidental commits.